# Why do I get a NPE when passing Bundle to a new Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my first Activity I'm putting stuff into a Bundle and then firing off the Intent:

```
b = new Bundle();
b.putString(Constants.KEY_CLASS, classSelected);
Intent i = new Intent(this, AssessmentMarksActivity.class);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

In the next Activity, I just get what I need from it:

```
tvClass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAssessmentClass);
b = getIntent().getExtras();
classSelected = b.getString(Constants.KEY_CLASS);
tvClass.setText(classSelected);
```

I get a NPE when I try to set the text of the TextView.

This is the XML for the Text View:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvAssessmentMarksClass"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:text="Class"
android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tvClass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAssessmentClass);
```

Seems the ids are not the same, thus causing your NPE.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvAssessmentMarksClass"
    ...
```

Comment: OOPS.. Thanks, the correct id is R.id.tvAssessmentMarksClass Just missed the 'Marks'